# nth selector jquery displaying nth value

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to choose an nth child from a list of spans and display their nth value (or position) on button click.

So if I have:

```
item a
item b
item c
item d
item e
```

on button press I want it to display:

```
1 item a
2 item b
3 item c
4 item d
5 item e
```

is this possible and if so how?

The HTML (from answer below)

```
<div class="items">item a</div>
<div class="items">item b</div>
<div class="items">item c</div>
<div class="items">item d</div>
<div class="items">item e</div>
```

Comment: The HTML as provided by Pulkit is almost exactly how it is.

Comment: Pretty quick with the close button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what can be done:

If HTML is

```
<div class="items">item a</div>
<div class="items">item b</div>
<div class="items">item c</div>
<div class="items">item d</div>
<div class="items">item e</div>
```

JS should be:

```
$(function(){
    $('.items').each(function(index){
        $(this).html((index+1)+" "+$(this).html());
    });
});
```

​
DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/veZg5/